# The Asof join engine output does not match expectations

Tags: streaming, cumulative-sum, dolphindb

Why does the cumsum calculation for the TV column restart at the red line, even though the calculations before it are correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The window function like cumsum is not applicable within the Asof join engine; it should be split into two separate engines: one for the Asof join engine and another for the reactive state engine (used for computing cumsum, prev, etc.). These two engines should then be linked together to implement the computing logic.